# Directive binding only works after clicking on element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a tooltip directive in angularjs but there is a problem: I have to click on the element before the directive works. After clicking on the element the directive works fine, but this isn't what I want. The idea is that I want to be able to hover over the element and then see the tooltip. How can I get the binding to work without having to first click on the element?

```
myApp.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { loc: "@" },
        replace: false,
        templateUrl: 'partials/tooltip.html',
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.tooltip_content = attrs.title;
            scope.tooltip_placement = 'tooltip_' + attrs.placement;
            element.bind("mouseenter",function(){
                scope.hover = true;
            });
            element.bind("mouseleave",function(){
                scope.hover = false;
            });
        }
    };
});


<div tooltip loc="somewhere" title="Show Message" placement="left">
    <div class="my_class">Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding to a native event like `mouseenter`, you need to give Angular a nudge so that it will force a digest cycle and update the scope.  You do this with `$scope.$apply`.  So, in each of your bind functions add an `$apply`:

```
element.bind("mouseenter",function(){
    scope.hover = true;
    scope.$apply();
});
```

This should update the scope value.

BTW, clicking on the element probably did the job of running a digest.  That is why you saw the scope update after a click.